# How to connect two virtual machines in different Host machines

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

How to connect two virtual machine(Ubuntu) created by VMware Player in different Host Machines?

One virtual machine(Ubuntu)  in Win XP Host machine and another virtual machine(Ubuntu) in Win 7. I am not able to ping between two virtual machine.But I am able to ping between two virtual machine if they are in the same Host machine.

Please reply .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting both machines to "bridged" networking, not "NAT" nor "Host-only".

Comment: Thanks its working for me.Actually I got the same info from this link http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_common.html